# When does heightForHeaderInSection gets called

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am calling the following function to update the tableView. However, I am finding that heightForHeaderInSection gets called twice for each section there are in the table. So if I have 5 sections, the function gets called 10 times. Is that normal?

```
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    let sections = NSIndexSet(index:posts.count - 1)
    tableView.insertSections(sections, withRowAnimation: .None)
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Yes, it is normal!

Comment: Why does it need to be called twice

Comment: IDK, someone might explain, lets wait. But its normal.

Comment: How many visible sections are presented ?

Comment: On the screen I can see 2 section maximum as they are quite big with image

Comment: You don't need to `beginUpdates() & endUpdates()` to do a single operation. You use it when you are inserting and deleting in batches.

Answer (score 2):

To answer youre question lets look at `UITableViewDelegate`. From Apple documentation :

> The delegate of a UITableView object must adopt the
>   UITableViewDelegate protocol. Optional methods of the protocol allow
>   the delegate to manage selections, configure section headings and
>   footers, help to delete and reorder cells, and perform other actions.

So when `UITableViewDelegate` is get called in your'e case? Delegate is get called when you update `tableView` with `insertSections`. So `heightForHeaderInSection` is called after you insert new sections to `tableView`.

Amount of times that `heightForHeaderInSection` is get called depends on how you update `tableView`.

Also it is possible to highlight that Apple do not gives clear explanation how often UIKit would call you're delegate methods.